# How to add Default Background if ListView / Adapter is empty

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Here is an example of what I am saying in title.  Take the app "Feedly".  If there is even ONE item i your list, it looks like this:

[image]

Now, if the list is empty, there is a nice way to handle this to avoid a big, blank, white space, like so:

[image]

How can one achieve this?

Off hand I am thinking maybe this way, see my pseudo-code:

```
if (adapter.size < 1) {
  // change ListView Background;
}
```

Comment: You use an `ImageView` with the desired image as the empty view.

Comment: @Luksprog  And how do you check for the empty view?  Like I mentioned above or another way?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29 and you pass the `ImageView` and the `ListView` will take care of it on its own.

Comment: Wow, had no idea there was such a specific `method` for this!  Feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: No need for that, mark Matthew's answer as correct.

Comment: @Luksprog  Hey I got this working.  One thing I found, is `header` on the list no longer shows... is this normal?

Comment: I guess so. The header/footer are not taken in consideration for the `adapter.getCount()`(I hope I'm not having a memory loss).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [ListView#setEmptyView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

If your have an empty ListView, the height should be 0 and it may be no use to set the background for ListView.

I have several solutions here:

1. Set the background for the LinearLayout/RelativeLayout, whatever which contain the ListView according to size of adapter.
2. Create another ImageView which is the "All read" image, and set its visibility according to data size of the ListView adapter.
3. Create a view for what you want to display when adapter size = 0, and use [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) to switch between ListView and "All read" view according to adapter size.  I will recommend this one since it may be more flexible for the "All read" view. You can have button, TextView, ImageView or whatever layout element you want to put in it.

2 and 3 are similar but using ViewSwitcher may make the code readability better than setting Visibility for views.

Here is an [example](http://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/using-a-viewswitcher-in-your-android-xml-layouts/) for using ViewSwitcher.